# Установка и использование RHVoice

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, g++, tts

Сейчас разбираюсь с синтезом речи, самым лучшем вариантом показался RHVoice. Установил по инструкции в [репозитории](https://github.com/Olga-Yakovleva/RHVoice/blob/0.3/INSTALL). Но при попытке выполнить

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <RHVoice/core/engine.hpp>
#include <RHVoice/core/document.hpp>
#include <RHVoice/core/client.hpp>
#include <RHVoice/RHVoice.h>
#include <RHVoice/RHVoice_common.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace RHVoice;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   RHVoice_init_params tts_params;
   RHVoice_tts_engine tts = RHVoice_new_tts_engine(&tts_params);
   cout << RHVoice_get_voices(tts) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

вылетает ошибка:

```
$ g++ -o main -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/utf8 -I/usr/local/include/rapidxml main.cpp 
/tmp/ccFaZI1M.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `RHVoice_new_tts_engine'
main.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `RHVoice_get_voices'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

RHVoice находится в

```
$ ls /usr/local/include/RHVoice
audio.hpp  core  RHVoice_common.h  RHVoice.h  SConscript
```

Объясните пожалуйста, какие флаги нужно прописать компилятору или как правильно установить RHVoice?
Пожалуйста, покажите, как правильно говорить с RHVoice?